# How to create an array of pointers for dgemm_batch with fortran?

Tags: fortran, blas, intel-mkl

I want to use the mkl subroutine dgemm_batch in a fortran code. Reference manual can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-gemm-batch)

I want to know how to create an array of pointers for the a_array, b_array and c_array?

The intel manual implies that there are actually of type integer not pointer.

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. You should show us your current code even if the part you want the help with is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

In Intel Fortran and some other compilers you can get an address of an object by a non-standard function [`LOC()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-loc). It is not a standard Fortran function, but passing pointers in an integer array is not a standard way either.